# how to know that a mailitem has arrived in the folder

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I have to write a code when the user clicks on the Send button to move a mailitem to a folder **My Folder** and stop the sending functionality.
I have achieved this through Below Code:

```
       void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
        {
                Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
                Cancel = true;
                if (mailItem != null)
                {
                    var attachments = mailItem.Attachments;

                    string folderPath =
                      Application.Session.
                      DefaultStore.GetRootFolder().FolderPath
                      + @"\Outbox\My Outbox";
                    Outlook.Folder folder = GetFolder(folderPath);
                    if (folder != null)
                    {
                        mailItem.Move(folder);

                    }
                  }
         }
```

My question is that I have to trigger a code piece when a mailitem arrive in the My Outbox folder.
I am a newbie in VSTO and plugins . Kindly tell me how can I achieve this.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect when an item has been added into a Outlook folder you need to use the [ItemAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609%28v=office.15%29.aspx) event on the [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863652%28v=office.15%29.aspx) collection of the [Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863890%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Below is an example on how to detect when a [MailItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861332%28v=office.15%29.aspx) is added into the Inbox folder.
Add the following code in the ThisAddIn.cs file:

```
private Items _inboxItems;

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    MAPIFolder inboxFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    _inboxItems = inboxFolder.Items;

    _inboxItems.ItemAdd += InboxItems_ItemAdd;

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(inboxFolder);
}

private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_inboxItems);
}

private void InboxItems_ItemAdd(object item)
{    
    if (item is MailItem)
    {
        // Add your code here        
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, the ItemAdd event is not 100% reliable if more than 16 items are being delivered/copied/moved to the folder at the same time - so there's a chance a message could be missed.  For handling newly delivered emails specifically, you can use the Application.NewMail or Application.NewMailEx events.